# How to transliterate Japanese text to ASCII (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, internationalization, transliteration

I've done some research and can't find any way to transliterate Japanese.

Stringex would have been the best bet, but it's a [known issue](https://github.com/rsl/stringex/pull/85) that it treats Japanese as Mandarin. I've verified this happens even when there are obvious Japanese characters present (ie kana). Same for Unidecoder.

I realise it's a hard problem as Kanji phonetics are ambiguous, but this is for URL slugs so it doesn't have to be perfect.

Comment: Do you need to transliterate at all? UTF-8 should be fine in slugs these days.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @muistooshort You may be right, I'd need to check general compatibility. I'd still want to do this for other reasons though, such as username suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried it, but you could try this:

https://github.com/makimoto/romaji

"Romaji" is basically the name for system the Japanese themselves use to write in Roman/Latin characters. I am not certain if transliterations targetted at romaji for Japanese speakers will be what you need if you are targetting non-Japanese speakers, but it seems like it might be good.

So you could try `romaji` in your google searching, that's what I did. Since ruby, of course, originated in Japan, I figured there'd be something around for it.